# How can I recur a Zio schedule until a particular value is produced?

Tags: scala, zio

Suppose I have an IO (therefore unsafe) operation that will either return `true` or `false`.  I want to use the Zio scheduling mechanism to execute this until the value is `true`, but only up to a maximum of N times.  To adopt the code from [the documentation](https://zio.dev/docs/usecases/usecases_scheduling) and change it to what I'm trying to achieve...

```
import zio._
import zio.duration._
import zio.console._
import zio.clock._
import java.util.Random

object API {
  // our API method will return true about 30% of the time, but
  // return false the rest of the time (instead of throwing an
  // exception, as is shown in documentation)
  def makeRequest: Task[Boolean] = Task.effect {
    new Random().nextInt(10) > 7
  }
}

object ScheduleUtil {
  def schedule[A] = Schedule.spaced(1.second) && Schedule.recurs(4).onDecision({
    case Decision.Done(_)                 => putStrLn(s"done trying")
    case Decision.Continue(attempt, _, _) => putStrLn(s"attempt #$attempt")
  })
}

import ScheduleUtil._
import API._

object ScheduleApp extends scala.App {

  implicit val rt: Runtime[Clock with Console] = Runtime.default

  rt.unsafeRun(makeRequest.retry(schedule).foldM(
    ex => putStrLn("Exception Failed"),
    v => putStrLn(s"Succeeded with $v"))
  )
}

// run the app
ScheduleApp.main(Array())
```

This doesn't work, of course.  The output is either `Succeeded with false` or (occasionally) `Succeeded with true`.  I tried adding `Schedule.recurUntilEquals` to the `Schedule` definition, but to no avail.

```
object ScheduleUtil {
    def schedule[A] = Schedule.spaced(1.second) && Schedule.recurUntilEquals(true) && Schedule.recurs(4).onDecision({
      case Decision.Done(_)                 => putStrLn(s"done trying")
      case Decision.Continue(attempt, _, _) => putStrLn(s"attempt #$attempt")
    })
  }

import ScheduleUtil._

// re-define ScheduleApp in the exact same way as above, and the following error results:

cmd93.sc:5: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [A]zio.Schedule[zio.console.Console,Boolean,((Long, Boolean), Long)]
    (which expands to)  [A]zio.Schedule[zio.Has[zio.console.Console.Service],Boolean,((Long, Boolean), Long)]
 required: zio.Schedule[?,Throwable,?]
  rt.unsafeRun(makeRequest.retry(schedule).foldM(
```

How can I accomplish such a use case using the Zio scheduler?  Of course, I can redefine the `makeRequest` task to deliberately throw an exception, instead of returning false, and this works just as in the documentation.  But I was hoping to avoid unnecessary exception generation/handling.

```
object API {
    // our API method will return true about 30% of the time, but
    // return false the rest of the time (instead of throwing an
    // exception, as is shown in documentation)
    def makeRequest = Task.effect {
      if (new Random().nextInt(10) > 7) true else throw new Exception("Not true")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the you are using `retry` on the `effect` instead of `repeat` which is what you want since you will be explicitly bypassing the error channel as you mentioned.

So simply change `makeRequest.retry(schedule)` to `makeRequest.repeat(schedule)` and it should work.

For a more detailed description consider the signatures below:

```
// Schedule.spaced
def spaced(duration: Duration): Schedule[Any, Any, Long]

// Schedule.recurs
def recurs(n: Int): Schedule[Any, Any, Long]

// Schedule.recurUntilEquals
def recurUntilEquals[A](a: => A): Schedule[Any, A, A]
```

`Schedule` has three type parameters, `-Env`, `-In`, `+Out`, the `Env` is the same as the standard `R` type that is part of `ZIO`, but `In` and `Out` are different from the standard `E` and `A` on the other `ZIO` types. This is because the `Schedule` describes "recurring schedule, which consumes values of type `In`, and which returns values of type `Out`"  according to the docs. For `spaced` and `recurs` the input is `Any` indicating that it will accept any input value and by extension also doesn't constrain the value. You can see this by composing the two together:

```
val s: Schedule[Any, Any, (Long, Long)] = Schedule.spaced(1.second) && Schedule.recurs(1)
```

This is also why it doesn't cause any compiler errors when used as part of `retry`, because they don't have any specific requirements on the error channel when they don't make use of it. *But* this also hides your problem because `retry` only uses the schedule if there is an *error* but since you were returning `true` or `false` you didn't end up receiving an error and your schedule was never invoked.

Once you added the `recurUntilEquals` an input constraint is added to the schedule:

```
val s: Schedule[Any, Boolean, ((Long, Long), Boolean)] = Schedule.spaced(1.second) && Schedule.recurs(1) && Schedule.recurUntilEquals(true)
```

Now you are saying that the input that should be fed into the `Schedule` is actually a boolean, but `retry` has the signature:

```
def retry[R1 <: R, S](policy: Schedule[R1, E, S])(implicit ev: CanFail[E]): ZIO[R1 with Clock, E, A]
```

Notice that the second position of the `Schedule` in the `policy` argument is the `E` parameter which is the error type and since `Throwable` =!= `Boolean` you get a compiler error as a result.

Correspondingly this is the signature for `repeat`

```
def repeat[R1 <: R, B](schedule: Schedule[R1, A, B]): ZIO[R1 with Clock, E, B]
```

Here we see that the `schedule` actually takes the `A` type which in this case would be the response from your API or `Boolean` which matches with what you are expecting in your provided schedule.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this answer, which really helps in my understanding of Zio.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ZIO.repeatWhile(task)(condition) which works pretty well for my case.